# how to create a view of multiple columns from one column structure in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, database, view, oracle11g, multiple-columns

suppose that i have a table named **PROFILE** and one column of it is **names** like below:

```
|NAMES|
-------
JAMES
-------
ANDY
-------
PETER
-------
SARAH
-------
JESSICA
-------
RACHEL
```

How could i make a view so that it shows like this:

```
|col1  | col2| col3   |
-------|-----|--------|
|JAMES  |PETER|JESSICA|
-------|-----|------- |
|ANDY   |SARAH|RACHEL |
----------------------
```

The reason i'm in need of this is because i need to use it with apex report page,i'm planning to do a grid style layout.Kinda hard to explain but thats the structure i would 
like to achieve. Would it be possible? and would the query be too many lines?

Comment: What relates which records go to which columns?  Could it be more than 3 columns (i.e. are you looking for a dynamic number of columns)?

Comment: Could you elaborate on names' ordering? Why JAMES|PETER|JESSICA? Or you just want to split into groups of three names?

Comment: Does your `PROFILE` table always have exactly six rows or are you trying to dynamically create columns?  It looks like you want the "odd" numbered rows from `PROFILE` distributed across the first row of the result and the "even" numbered rows across the second.  Is that correct?

Comment: @user2480596, for now i would like it to be three columns. if i could understand the solution i might make it into two columns having 3rows. basically i would want to know how to split from one column to multiple columns.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov, i just want to split it into groups of three for this case.

Comment: @BellevueBob, in this case i will assume it has static 6 rows.doesnt need to be odd or even. i just want to split data into the three columns. preferably in the same order from when it was in a single column.

Comment: The answer just given is what I had in mind; the "odd"/"even" part is defining the two output rows using the `MOD` function.  If your data is exactly as described, it should work well.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you always need 3 columns, then this will work using `MAX` with `CASE` to perform a pivot, along with `ROW_NUMBER()` and `MOD()`:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN name END) col1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN name END) col2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN name END) col3
FROM (
  SELECT Row_Number() Over (Partition By MOD(ROWNUM,2) Order By Null) rn, MOD(ROWNUM,2) whichGroup, name
  FROM profile
  ) talias
GROUP BY whichGroup
```

Use `MOD` to get which rows and use `Row_Number` for your pivot.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46149/1

-- Please note, without adding a field to your `ORDER BY` clause, you won't be able to guarantee a specific order to the results.

Comment: thanks @user2480596 . dont really understand about the order by in your note.if i were to need order by,where and how should i put it? i tried to put it after FROM profile but didnt work. need the names in the same sequential order.would it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to approach this is to use Oracle's built-in `rownum` variable and then use integer division (to determine the row) and `mod()` to determine the column:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN mod(seqnum, 3) = 0 THEN name END) as col1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN mod(seqnum, 3) = 1 THEN name END) as col2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN mod(seqnum, 3) = 2 THEN name END) as col3
FROM (SELECT name, rownum as seqnum
      FROM profile
     ) t
GROUP BY trunc((seqnum - 1) / 3)
```